Modeling, why do surfaces look curved?
There is an unnatural shadow on the surface and it feels very strange.
It feels strange even with a smooth shader, and it feels strange even when displayed with a flood shade.
The direction of the normal is correct, and the only way to improve this is to redraw the surface.
In the image below, the surface appears curved and there are unnatural shadows.

The image below is the pattern with the surface reattached.
Unnatural shadows are gone.
However, it is difficult to apply this to all aspects that feel uncomfortable.

This is the smooth shader version.
Still feels strange

There are many faces, edges, and vertices here. As a result, I thought it looked strange and that there was a shadow, but when I compared other parts of this mesh, I found that the same phenomenon did not occur.

What is the reason for such an event?
I don't want to use a subdivided surface because I want to eventually bring it to the unreal engine.
if you'd kindly teach me.


Go to Object Data Properties > Geometry Data and click on the button Clear Custom Split Normals Data. I do not know how you created the custom split normals (there are different possible ways), but once you got rid of them the shading is back to normal.


thank you ！！Learn about custom split normal on your own

@vectorman What do you mean by "learn about custom split normal on your own"?
